# General undergraduate zoology textbook recommendation?

Tags: zoology, book-recommendation

I am very interested in zoology,and I want to study zoology in my spare time.
Any undergraduate level zoology text book recommendation?

Comment: This is a rather broad question. In an attempt to narrow things down: Are there specific areas of zoology in which you are interested?  Are there specific types of textbooks that you like more than others (or what do you *not* enjoy in a textbook)?

Comment: @dd3 general introductory level zoology textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Zoology by Miller and Harley](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073524174) in my undergraduate years and I found it to be an engaging, informative text book.

Answer (score 2):

LIFE : The Science of Biology by Sadava & Hills & Hellar & Berenbaum